# How many Tie-Fighters can a Star Destroyer carry?

Tags: star-wars

Watched *Rogue One* today and was wondering how many [Tie-Fighters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE/LN_starfighter) a [Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Destroyer) can carry?

Is there are any official data about it or some information to approximate the number?

Comment: Lots. And lots.

Comment: @Valorum: And yet, not enough.

Comment: @Ellesedil - You have to remember that the Empire's overwhelming failure is overconfidence. If they simply set about murdering their opponents with utmost alacrity, each film would have ended with the Rebels losing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Main Canon

According to the [Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook, [Imperial I-Class Star Destroyers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_I-class_Star_Destroyer) can apparently field up to **72 TIE/LN fighters.**

> *In the Battle of Endor, **Star Destroyers deploy wings of 72 TIE
>   starfighters, benefiting the war effort, but rebel fighters
>   nonetheless exploit vulnerabilities in the Destroyers' shield
>   generators and exposed bridges.** Imperial I-class Star Destroyers prove
>   far less effective against fleets of skilled rebel pilots than their
>   Venator-class predecessors were against droid starfighters.*

---

The [Imperial II-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_II-class_Star_Destroyer) also fields a similar complement, according to the canon comic [Shattered Empires, Part III.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shattered_Empire,_Part_III)

[image]

---

### Legends canon

Moving down the canon scale, we learn in the [Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels) factbook that the Imperial I-Class Star Destroyer's fighters are typically arranged into smaller *squadrons*. The vessel also fielded a range of other support craft.

> ***A full wing of seventy-two TIE fighters (six squadrons of twelve ships
>   each) is standard aboard each Destroyer. As of the Battle of Yavin, a
>   standard Star Destroyer maintained four squadrons of standard TIE/lns,
>   one squadron of TIE interceptors, and one squadron of TIE bombers.***
>   (Lower-priority vessels have a squadron of TIE/gts.) By the time of
>   the Battle of Endor, an additional TIE interceptor squadron had
>   replaced one of the TIE/ln squadrons.
>
> *Support ships, all maintained aboard the Destroyer, include eight
>   Lambda-class shuffles, fifteen stormtrooper transports, five assault
>   gunboats, and a variable number of Skipray blastboats and Gamma-class
>   assault shuffles.*

And from the same source we learn that Vader's Super Star Destroyer, [the Executor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Executor/Legends#cite_note-SOTG2007-4) had *two* full wings of TIE Fighters, a total of 144.

> *Bristling with over a thousand weapons, including tur- bolasers,
>   concussion-missile tubes, tractor-beam projectors, and ion cannons,
>   Super Star Destroyers wielded awesome firepower. They held two full
>   wings of TIE fighters, for 144 ships, as well as 200 other combat and
>   support ships.*

And we learn from the [Starships of the Galaxy RPG Rulebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starships_of_the_Galaxy_(Saga_Edition)) that the [Victory-II Class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_II-class_Star_Destroyer) has a small wing of just 24 fighters.

> *Though smaller and less durable than the Imperial II-class Star Destroyer, the Victory II-class ships are still incredibly powerful
>   and often operate in pairs. Since the ship lacks a large TIE fighter
>   complement, the Victory II-class Star Destroyer is often paired with
>   escort ships or fleet carriers that have a large number of
>   starfighters that can be quickly deployed.*
>
> **Carried Craft:** **24 TIE fighters**

Comment: I seem to remember, in the West End Games Star Wars RPG books, it was claimed that Grand Moff Tarkin preferred the Victory-II Star Destroyer as a flagship. Those books are long gone so I can't look it up.